# finding the sum of a 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, compiler-errors

I'm new to java and I have to find the sum of a 2D array but my code simply won't compile.  I keep getting the errors :

3 errors found:

```
File: C:\Users\Brett\Documents\DrJava\Matrix.java  [line: 9]
Error: length cannot be resolved or is not a field
File: C:\Users\Brett\Documents\DrJava\Matrix.java  [line: 10]
Error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int
File: C:\Users\Brett\Documents\DrJava\Matrix.java  [line: 15]
Error: The constructor Matrix(int[][]) is undefined
```

I have no idea how to fix them, thanks in advance for the help!

```
public class Matrix {
  int[] matrix;
  Matrix(int[] matrix) {
    this.matrix = matrix;
  }
  int sum() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
      sum += matrix[i][j];
    return sum;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a1 = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    Matrix m1 = new Matrix(a1);
    System.out.println(m1.sum());
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow don't know why the errors printed like that

Comment: You have one-dimensional arrays, yet try to use them as if they're two-dimensional.

Comment: Specifically, your `a1` declared in `main` is two-dimensional, but your `matrix` field is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
int[][] a1 = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
Matrix m1 = new Matrix(a1);
```

**Java doesn't see a constructor that accepts an `int[][]`.**  Your constructor only accepts `int[]`.  Hence, the error message.

You would want to change your constructor (and matrix field, for that matter) accordingly:

```
int[][] matrix;
Matrix(int[][] matrix) {
    this.matrix = matrix;
}
```

Comment: Ah ha! I knew it would be something silly... I was looking all over my methods :( Thank you though I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You also can use third-party library for this. For example, [la4j](http://la4j.org):

```
Matrix a = new Basic2DMatrix(new double[][] {
  { 1.0, 2.0 },
  { 3.0, 4.0 }
});

System.out.println(a.sum()); // easy-peasy
```